# restricting the domain of the unbounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, control-theory

Can anyone give me a a restricted non-void set of bounded inputs which results in bounded outputs, though the operator is not bounded on the whole space (consider L2-space).

One can consider a simple differential equation
$\frac{d}{dt}y - \alpha y = \frac{d}{dt}u, \alpha >0$, where $u$ should be considered as the input and $y$ as the output.

From the control theoretic viewpoint, the above system is clearly unstable because it has a pole in RHP of s-plane. Therefore, for a bounded input the output will be unbounded as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: What do you mean by an operator being unbounded?

Comment: Is the issue somewhat clear to you? @Ilya. I edited the question!